# Scaling tf.io.gfile.GFile over 100MB/s throughput

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

To keep a GPU fully utilized during training I need to be able to feed about 250 MB/s of raw data to the GPU (the data is uncompressible). I am accessing the data over a fast network which can feed well over 2GB/sec without a problem. Python's GIL makes it rather hard to get those speeds into the same process that runs Tensorflow without negatively impacting the training loop. Python 3.8's shared memory may alleviate this, but that's not supported by Tensorflow just yet.

So I'm using `tf.io.gfile.GFile` to read data over the network (data is stored on a high bandwidth S3 compliant interface). The value of `GFile` is that it doesn't engage the GIL, and thus plays nicely with the training loop. In order to achieve high throughput there needs to be significant parallelization of the network IO.

I only seem to be able to get about 75-100 MB/sec out this approach though.

I've timed two approaches:

- Create a `tf.data.Dataset` and use `tf.data.Dataset.map(mymapfunc, num_parallel_calls=50)` (I've tried many values of num_parallel_calls including AUTOTUNE).
- Create a function that reads data using `tf.io.gfile.GFile` and simply run it using multiple threads in a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, attempting thread counts up to about 100 (there's no improvement above about 20, and eventually more threads slow it down).

In both cases I'm topping out at 75-100 MB/sec.

**Questions:**

> I'm wondering if there's a reason for `GFile` to hit an upper limit that is perhaps more
>   obvious to someone else.
>
> I'm also making an assumption I should validate: `tf.io.gfile.GFile`
>   runs in numpy land, in both cases above I'm running `GFile` operations
>   from python land (in the case of `tf.data.Dataset` I'm using
>   `tf.py_function`). If GFile is meant to run as part of the graph
>   operations more efficiently I'm unaware of this and need to be
>   corrected.

Comment: Yes, from the S3 side the admins have monitoring showing that when I run multiple jobs, and from my my side I've benchmarked 1+GB/sec into a single pod using multiple Python processes running asyncio and 500-1000 parallel operations against the S3 interface. It's a large kubernetes cluster running Ceph distributed filesystem. I'm pretty darn confident that the bottleneck isn't at S3, but if anyone else has seen higher than 100MB/sec from gfile I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: However you can't move 1GB/sec of data from one python process to another without pretty much fully locking the GIL in the main python process, which blocks a tensorflow training loop from iterating quickly and thus hampers the GPU , so until I can try python 3.8 and SystemV shared memory, neither multiprocessing nor multithreading have played nicely with a training loop on the GPU. This is where the appeal of gfile comes in, it doesn't lock the GIL.

Comment: When you say you tried `Dataset.map` was it like `DatasetReader(filename).map(...)`? That tries to squeeze all the data through one one. Have you looked at `Dataset.interleave`, which would be more like `FileNamesDataset().interleave(lambda f:DatasetReader(f))` streaming over multiple connections... There used to be a "sloppy_interleave" option which increased performance because it could skip a stalled connection... but that seems gone in tf2 maybe it's hidden in `tf.data.Options.experimental_deterministic`.

Comment: The `map` receives a set of file segments to download (filename, offset, length) of size 5-30 MB, and the map function opens a gfile for each segment and performs `seek` and `read`. There doesn't appear to be any appreciable overhead opening a gfile against an S3 interface, so I haven't cached that operation. I'm expecting `num_parallel_calls` is parallelizing that. And since I see the same behavior with a threadpool I didn't question the map operation too much.

Comment: "The map receives a set of file segments to download" That sounds good.
"of size 5-30 MB" I've heard recommendations of 100s of MB per file for maximum performance, but who knows if that will help.

Comment: Just to make sure, when you say you have tried using `tf.data.Dataset`, I assume you have already gone through the [data performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance) and use things like [`prefetch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch) right?

Comment: I'm just reading and discarding from the dataset in a loop. I have applied prefetch with a large buffer. I think the solution I'm arriving at is to do the IO in subprocesses but pipe the results to tensorflow via `tfrecord` files. That way I can parallelize IO is whatever way I need to  (`asyncio` is much faster than `tf.io.gfile`, but locks the GIL). TFRecordReader will push serialization off to the tensorflow C libraries where the GIL isn't locked (trying to serialize between python processes locks the GIL and delays the training loop). I just hand off a `tfrecords` filename between procs's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultimate resolution to this question for me is as follows:

- I could not get GFile to download at a particularly high rate, `boto3.Client.download_file` is much faster as it employs multiple threads.
- I have kicked off a separate process (`multiprocessing`) to handle the IO via boto3, it downloads a continuously rolling window of a large (terabyte+) dataset locally.
- Another process then samples the local files and writes TF Records files to a RAM disk, then it passes the filenames off to a `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` as they are written.
- It was necessary to hand off large scale data streams to tensorflow via TFRecords files because deserialization in Python will lock the GIL and delay the training loop (notably Python 3.8's System V shared memory may solve this problem, but [TF 2.2 is the first version expected to support Python 3.8](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33374)).
- The RAM disk avoided overloading the IO, though I still needed NVMe level IO performance to simultaneously download (100 MB/sec IO) and read the raw data files and generate tf records (200 MB/sec of IO).
- My ultimate solution for dealing with a terabyte+ dataset that doesn't fully fit locally was to download a continuously rolling window of raw data files locally via boto3, and run 2 processes sampling from the available local files and writing TF Records files to a RAM disk, then handing those filenames off to a `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` as they're generated. The components can be written in a nearly fully decoupled manner, so it's not terrible to debug.
- With this solution the GPU remains >90%. IO requires about 300MB/sec aggregate read/write. Memory usage: ~10GB in RAM disk, and ~5GB RAM in processes. This model feeds on about 200MB/sec of raw (uncompressable) data.